# How to save the state of accordion using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I wanted to save the state of the accordion and keeping it after the page refresh.

So far here is script.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').accordion({
     header: '.category',
     collapsible: true,
     active: localStorage.getItem('accordion-active')||false
     });
});
  window.onload = function(){
  localStorage.setItem('accordion-active',$('table').accordion('option','active'));
};
 </script>
```

[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xyjy/266/)

but it seems I couldn't make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: At first, there would not be state of accordion as you set it later, is this okay with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do that by storing the index of the current active accordion in the `acivate` event, and then use it in the `active` option on pageload

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('table').accordion({
         header: '.category',
         collapsible: true,
         activate: function(e, ui) {
             localStorage.setItem('accordion-active', $(this).accordion( "option", "active" ));
         },
         active: +localStorage.getItem('accordion-active')
     });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xyjy/273/)

Comment: It works fine in this example but I wonder how does it work on tbody that are dynamically populated? It seems that when I tried this code. When I click the first accordion and refreshes the second accordion copies the state of the first one?

Comment: If you have multiple tables or accordions, you would of course have to create a new instance for each one, with a new key for localStorage etc ?

Comment: Do you have a sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('table').accordion({
     header: '.category',
     collapsible: true,
     activate: function(e, ui) {
         localStorage.setItem('accordion-active', $(this).accordion( "option", "active" ));
     },
     active: parseInt(localStorage.getItem('accordion-active'))
 });
});
```

Use parseInt(localStorage.getItem('accordion-active')) for active option if you want all of the tables in the accordion to load as collapsed initially.