# Multiple JQuery Accordions On Page load collapsed but remember last active when link on page is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion, session-storage

I need to have multiple accordions on a page so that I can have them open at the same time and I need the browser to remember the last active accordion or accordions when a link on the page has been clicked until the next session. However, I need the accordions to start out as collapsed.

This is what I have thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583852/how-to-save-the-state-of-accordion-using-localstorage):

```
<div id="accordion-one" class="genericClass">
    <h3 class="genericHeading">Heading1</h3>
    <div class="genericSub">
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data1</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data2</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data3</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data4</a></div>         
    </div>
</div>
<div id="accordion-two" class="genericClass">
    <h3 class="genericHeading">Heading2</h3>
    <div class="genericSub">
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data1</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data2</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data3</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data4</a></div>         
    </div>
</div>
<div id="accordion-three" class="genericClass">
    <h3 class="genericHeading">Heading3</h3>
    <div class="genericSub">
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data1</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data2</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data3</a></div>
         <div class="genericData"><a href="#" target="_parent">Data4</a></div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('.genericClass').each(function(i,elem) {
    $(this).accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         navigation: true,
         activate: function(e, ui) {
             sessionStorage.setItem('accordion-active'+i, $(this).accordion( "option", "active"));
         },
         active: false && +sessionStorage.getItem('accordion-active'+i) 
    });
});
});
```

Here is a link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzwy289k/6/)

Any help? Because I can't figure out how to have all of the accordions at an initial session state of collapsed rather than them all being active on an intial session state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question I needed to add parseInt not false.

```
$(function() {
$('.genericClass').each(function(i,elem) {
    $(this).accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         navigation: true,
         activate: function(e, ui) {
             sessionStorage.setItem('accordion-active'+i, $(this).accordion( "option", "active"));
         },
         active: parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('accordion-active'+i)) 
    });
});
});
```

So anyone who wants to have multiple accordions on a page and have them load initially as collapsed but remember the active state within in a session can do it like this in HTML5 without needing cookies.